# Sitemap creation with DOMDocument throws parsing error

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I'm creating a sitemap in XML, it works well with one record displayed, but when including 1+ records, it throws an error:

> XML Parsing Error: junk after document element

Which shows this code here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<url><loc>http://www.mywebsite.com/page/1</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>0.6</priority></url>
<url><loc>http://www.mywebsite.com/page/2</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>0.6</priority></url>
```

My code:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
{
    $url = $xml->createElement('url');
    $xml->appendChild($url);

    $website_url = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/page/' . $i;

    $loc = $xml->createElement('loc', $website_url);
    $url->appendChild($loc);

    $change = $xml->createElement('changefreq', 'daily');
    $url->appendChild($change);

    $priority = $xml->createElement('priority', '0.6');
    $url->appendChild($priority);
}

header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

Why is it throwing this kind of error when the XML seems valid to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least in your example, you have two root nodes (`<url>`), as this is not allowed in xml, the second is the `junk after document element`.

You're missing the `<urlset>` root node, see: http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php